# How to access react router match object from mapstatetoprops

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

I was wondering how I would access the react-router match object for its params from mapStateToProps or any such selector. I wanted to build something out of the params and pass that down as props to the presentational component within the selector. I have a component that accepts a `built` prop and I'm hoping to pass it some value that's derived from the react router params.  I'd preferably would like to not have to pass params down as a prop.

Answer (score 1):

`mapStateToProps` takes [second parameter `ownProps`](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect). Once your component is initialized by `react-router` you gets `match` prop among your others.

```
<Route path="/details/:id" component={DetailsPage}
```

then

```
function DetailsPageComp(props) {
...
}


function mapStateToProps(state, { match: { params: {id} } }) {
  return {
    obj: someSelectorFunction(state, id);
  };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(DetailsPageComp);
```

Sure if you use `<Route render={}` version you need to pass `match` down:

```
<Route render={({ match }) => <DetailsPageComp match={match} />} path="..." />
```